# How to convert java Resultset into Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, jdbc, teradata

I am trying to use preparestatement with JDBC. It results ResultSet object. I want to convert it into spark dataframe.

```
object JDBCRead {

val tableName:String = "TABLENAME"
val url :String = "jdbc:teradata://TERADATA_URL/user=USERNAME,password=PWD,charset=UTF8,TYPE=FASTEXPORT,SESSIONS=10"
val  selectTable:String  = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName +" sample 10";

 val con : Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


 val pstmt2: PreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectTable)

import java.sql.ResultSet

val rs: ResultSet = pstmt2.executeQuery



val rsmd: ResultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData
while(rs.next()!=null)
{
  val k: Boolean = rs.next()
  for(i<-1 to rsmd.getColumnCount) {
    print(" " + rs.getObject(i))
  }
  println()
}

}
```

I want to call above code from Spark Dataframe so that I can load the data into dataframe and get the results faster distributedly.

I must use `PreparedStatement`. I can not use `spark.jdbc.load` since FASTEXPORT of Teradata does not work with jdbc load. It has to be used with `PreparedStatement`

How to achieve this? How can I user preparestatement along with SELECT statement to load into Spark Dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

-

> AFAIK there are 2 options available for this kind of requirements
>     1. `DataFrame`   2. `JdbcRDD`

***I'd offer [JdbcRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f830bb9170f6b853565d9dd30ca7418b93a54fe3/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.scala) (since you are so specific to preparedstatement)***

Which used prepareStatement internally in `compute` method. Therefore, you don't need to create connection and maintain it explicitly(error prone).

Later you can convert result in  to dataframe

For speed you can configure other parameters.

Example code usage of JdbcRDD is below..

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext.__
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
  import java.sql.{connection, DriverManager,ResultSet}


  object jdbcRddExample {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        // Connection String    
        VAL URL = "jdbc:teradata://SERVER/demo"
        val username = "demo"
        val password = "Spark"
        Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.Driver").newInstance
        // Creating & Configuring Spark Context
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App1").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory",1)
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        println("Start...")
        // Fetching data from Database
        val myRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc,() => DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password),
        "select first_name, last_name, gender from person limit ?,?",
        3,5,1,r => r.getString("last_name") + "," +r.getString("first_name"))
        // Displaying the content
        myRDD.foreach(println)
        // Saving the content inside Text File
        myRDD.saveAsTextFile("c://jdbcrdd")

        println("End...")
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks. Can you talk about the other method involving dataframe as well !!

Comment: How can JdbcRDD be converted to DataFrame?